# Поиск решения нелинейных задач методом ОПГ или подобным как в Excel для Python

Tags: python

коллеги,подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть методы в Python для решения многопараметрических нелинейных задач, которые в  Excel решаются методом ОПГ (поиск решения) или подобным способом?
Опишу задачу:
Я расчитываю стальную трубу на устойчивость. Моя задача подобрать такой начальный параметр mx*, чтобы прийти к заранее заданному значению решения ex0. Зависимость между ними нелинейная, но если бы существовала функция ex0(mx*), то она была бы возрастающей. Я прописала весь ход решения в excel и на python. В excel я просто пользовалась кнопкой "подбор параметра", а в python решала эту задачу методом дихотомии, задаваясь начальным и конечным значением mx*, и, таким образом постепенно приближалась к нужному ex0. Однако, это долгий метод. Какой метод можно применить вместо него? Какая там математика?

Для понимания на сколько задача не линейная, прикладываю схему расчета. По моему мнению стандартные решатели нелинейных уравнений тут не годятся. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему это метод дихотомии (он же "бинарного поиска", если правильно понимаю), медленный? Сколько же у вас один шаг считается?

Comment: Медленный, потому что получается около 20 итераций до решения. А мне нужно большой массив таким образом обсчитать, несколько тысяч вариантов. Сейчас нашла, что вроде бы метод хорд должен быть побыстрее.

Comment: А, и я все еще надеюсь на волшебную библиотеку, или даже функцию в python, о которой я еще не знаю)))

Comment: Если хотите библиотеку, то в `scipy` есть целый раздел оптимизации: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html